# File not attaching using play framework play mailer plugin

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, akka, email-attachments

We are using the below plugin for sending e-mails within our Play application. The sending e-mail part works perfectly OK but when I add an attachment, I am running into the below error which indicates the file is not present. Though I am 100% sure the file is present on my disk and also later it passes my vaidation test in code as well

Adding attachment in code

```
email.addAttachment(fileName,new File ("path"))
```

https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer

Error stack :

```
    2017-05-15 20:37:15,870 [ERROR] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10 - org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Cannot attach file "/tmp/playtemp7007305302758557514/multipartBody5483238492998817693asTemporaryFile"
    at org.apache.commons.mail.MultiPartEmail.attach(MultiPartEmail.java:334)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.play$api$libs$mailer$CommonsMailer$$handleAttachmentFile(MailerPlugin.scala:251)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer$$anonfun$createEmail$10.apply(MailerPlugin.scala:150)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer$$anonfun$createEmail$10.apply(MailerPlugin.scala:146)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.createEmail(MailerPlugin.scala:146)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:130)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:110)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPDynamicMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:117)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.MailerClient$class.send(MailerPlugin.scala:56)
    at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPDynamicMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:114)
```

Comment: Can you share the code, and also the full stack trace?

Comment: This is the best I can do since I cannot share code or further stacktrace. Can you please help. The attachments have started failing again.